# How to swap largest and smallest number in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a program that swaps largest and smallest number in multidimensional array. Largest number should be on the place where is the smallest, and smallest where is the largest, and the idea is to use pure logic, without any php function that could help me out.

Please check my code and help me about this problem.

For instance:

```
$array = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];
```

New order should be:

```
$array = [
  [906, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 45],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
]
```

I've tried with adding and changing code with this piece of code, but it doesn't give me right results...

```
$min_index = $max_index = 0;
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if($v < $array[$min_index]){
        $min_index = $k;
    }
    if($v > $array[$max_index]){
        $max_index = $k;
    }
}
$min = $array[$min_index];
$array[$min_index] = $array[$max_index];
$array[$max_index] = $min;
```

```
$array = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];

$intRows = 4;
$intCols = 4;

$intMaxRow = $intMinRow = $intMaxCol = $intMinCol = 0;

$minIndex = $maxIndex = 1;

for($row = 0; $row < $intRows; $row++)
{
  for($col = 0; $col < $intCols; $col++)
  {
    if($array[$row][$col] > $maxIndex)
    {
      $maxIndex = $array[$row][$col];
      $intMaxRow = $row;
      $intMaxCol = $col;
    }
    if($array[$row][$col] < $minIndex)
    {
      $minIndex = $array[$row][$col];
      $intMinRow = $row;
      $intMinCol = $col;
    }
  }
}

$arrNxm[$intMinRow][$intMinCol] = $minIndex;
$arrNxm[$intMaxRow][$intMaxCol] = $maxIndex;

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrNxm);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: In `[45, 456, 321, 344, 567]` how is the resultant array `[906, 456, 321, 344, 567]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some logical issues in your code which is causing it to not work.  You are going along the right lines though.

**Issue 1**

You have set the number of rows and columns incorrectly.  There are not 4, there are 5 of each:

```
$intRows = 5;
$intCols = 5;
```

**Issue 2**

The next issue is with:

```
$minIndex = $maxIndex = 1;
```

If `$minIndex` is `1`, then nothing in your array can be lower than it, so it's never going to be updated from 1.  This should be something like:

```
$minIndex = 100000; // This is an arbitrary choice to fix the issue
$maxIndex = 1;
```

**Issue 3**

Next, you use `$arrNxm` in your code.  There is no `$arrNxm`, it should be `$array`.

**Issue 4**

Finally, this is wrong because you are putting the minimum value *back into* the minimum position in the array:

```
$arrNxm[$intMinRow][$intMinCol] = $minIndex;
$arrNxm[$intMaxRow][$intMaxCol] = $maxIndex;
```

You just need to swap `$minIndex` and `$maxIndex` around:

```
$array[$intMinRow][$intMinCol] = $maxIndex;
$array[$intMaxRow][$intMaxCol] = $minIndex;
```

**Full code**

The fully working code is:

```
$array = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];

$intRows = 5;
$intCols = 5;

$intMaxRow = $intMinRow = $intMaxCol = $intMinCol = 0;

$minIndex = 100000;
$maxIndex = 1;

for($row = 0; $row < $intRows; $row++)
{
  for($col = 0; $col < $intCols; $col++)
  {
    if($array[$row][$col] > $maxIndex)
    {
      $maxIndex = $array[$row][$col];
      $intMaxRow = $row;
      $intMaxCol = $col;
    }
    if($array[$row][$col] < $minIndex)
    {
      $minIndex = $array[$row][$col];
      $intMinRow = $row;
      $intMinCol = $col;
    }
  }
}

$array[$intMinRow][$intMinCol] = $maxIndex;
$array[$intMaxRow][$intMaxCol] = $minIndex;

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

This outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(906)
    [1]=>
    int(456)
    [2]=>
    int(321)
    [3]=>
    int(344)
    [4]=>
    int(567)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(100)
    [1]=>
    int(434)
    [2]=>
    int(173)
    [3]=>
    int(400)
    [4]=>
    int(789)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(191)
    [1]=>
    int(211)
    [2]=>
    int(457)
    [3]=>
    int(809)
    [4]=>
    int(900)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(431)
    [1]=>
    int(323)
    [2]=>
    int(432)
    [3]=>
    int(805)
    [4]=>
    int(45)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(708)
    [1]=>
    int(232)
    [2]=>
    int(897)
    [3]=>
    int(101)
    [4]=>
    int(696)
  }
}
```

Whereby 45 and 906 are swapped in position as you wanted.

Comment: I'm so stupid. Thank you Martin for helping me out. Can you explain me just why setting $minIndex = 100000, and $maxIndex = 1? @Martin

Comment: @Developer12345 If you look at the code where you check to see whether the number in the array is lower, that can never be true in the minimum value is 1, because 1 is lower than all of the array values.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can change this code, to get the same results but without these two variables $minIndex = 100000;
$maxIndex = 1; ?

Comment: @Developer12345 Unfortunately not in this question as that is a completely separate issue